# Mobile layout issue

Tags: css, flexbox

My issue has to do with `#content`, and `#sidebar`. It works fine in browser, i.e., it displays in vertical form. But the mobile layout is all jumbled up, as in the `#sidebar` is overlaid the `#content` every time I view it on my iPhone.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Quicksand, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 100%;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  /*for content and sidebar */
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}


/* main */

#content {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 80%;
  flex: 1 1 80%;
  /* for header/logo and description */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#header {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 6%;
  flex: 1 0 6%;
  /* background-color: green; */
  /* for test */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

#test {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 10px;
}

#header h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Qwigley', cursive;
}

h1 {}

#description {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 55%;
  flex: 1 1 55%;
  /* background-color: yellow; */
  padding: 30px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

#description p {
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#description img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #db6525;
  display: none;
}

#description img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#flippedButterfly {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

#name {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #db6525;
}

#test img {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  /* for the following image and description */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
  align-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: none;
}

#sidebar {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 20%;
  flex: 1 0 20%;
  /* background-color: green; */
  text-align: center;
  /* for sidebar contents */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: distribute;
  align-content: space-around;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#js {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 10.0000%;
  flex: 1 0 10.0000%;
}

#js:hover {}

#js h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Qwigley', cursive;
}

#forms {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 11.11111%;
  flex: 1 0 11.11111%;
}

#forms:hover {}

#forms h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Qwigley', cursive;
}

#sites {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 11.11111%;
  flex: 1 0 11.11111%;
}

#sites:hover {}

#sites h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Qwigley', cursive;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Quicksand, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  body {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  main {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1 0 100%;
    flex: 1 0 100%;
    /*for content and sidebar */
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  /* main */
  #content {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 80%;
    flex: 1 1 80%;
    /* for header/logo and description */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #sidebar {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1 0 20%;
    flex: 1 0 20%;
    /* background-color: green; */
    text-align: center;
    /* for sidebar contents */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: distribute;
    align-content: space-around;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png" />
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Qwigley' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="normalize.css">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <section id="content">
      <article id="header">
        <section id="test">
          <img src='images/butterfly.png' />
          <h1>My WebSite</h1>
          <img id="flippedButterfly" src='images/butterfly.png' />
        </section>
      </article>
      <article id="description">
        <img src='#' />
        <p><span id="name">Hi, I'm </span><br /><br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sed volutpat sapien. Curabitur ultricies felis arcu, at rhoncus felis suscipit quis. Integer pulvinar <br /><br />sagittis enim at sodales.
          In eget tortor porta, faucibus magna eu, facilisis nulla. Proin at ex sed arcu tempor vehicula. Vestibulum volutpat arcu sed odio sollicitudin consequat. Sed nisi est, <br /><br />vestibulum vel vulputate sed, porta id sem. Sed metus ipsum,
          ullamcorper eget eleifend non, feugiat eget risus. Donec fermentum sodales ante sit amet viverra. Proin vitae erat auctor, sollicitudin ligula in, condimentum arcu. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
          mus.
        </p>
      </article>
    </section>
    <section id="sidebar">
      <article id="js">
        <h1>Javascript</h1>
        <p>Mini JS Projects</p>
        <p class="subtitle">Work in progress
      </article>
      <article id="forms">
        <h1>Free Forms</h1>
        <p>Feel free to download the forms</p>
      </article>
      <article id="sites">
        <h1>Portfolio</h1>
        <p>Combination of previous work and additional sites</p>
      </article>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you have `height: 100%` set on your containers (e.g., `html`, `body`, etc.). This limits the height of the container to the viewport height.

Since content cannot expand beyond the viewport limit, it is forced to overlap each other.

I would say, get rid of all `height: 100%` rules in your code.

Give your primary flex container `min-height: 100vh`.

Then work on the percentage heights of the children. With adjustments / removals, your layout works (i.e., the overlap is gone).

Comment: hm, I tried your original answer, ie, only primary flex container ... that didn't work, so tried this: http://jsbin.com/yotaheziso/edit?html,css,output ... it sort of works but there are still overlapping issues. Any ideas why?

Comment: You still have the percentage heights on flex properties, like `flex: 0 0 100%`. In a column-direction container, that's the same as `height: 100%`. You need to remove those.

Comment: ie, make them auto?

Comment: Start with that. Get rid of the overlap. Once that is fixed, try `flex-grow` to size the items.

Comment: only in the media queries, right? Leave the normal code alone?

Comment: Yes, start with that. See how it works. Post an updated demo if you get stuck again.

Comment: so it's like this now: http://jsbin.com/zewaginudu/edit?html,css,output ... I'm a bit startled that I have to manually have to write in `min-height: 100vh;` to almost everything make this work ... and this is for iphones only ... is this really completely responsive? What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: You don’t have to add the min-height, unless you want the container to have a minimum height. But you need to remove the height:100% if you don’t want a hard limit.

Comment: thank you! Still have questions, but since your answer helped to solve the original premise of the question, ie, the overlapping boxes, I should mark this as answered. Thank you.